# why I get highlight in intellij on a word indexOf

Tags: java, function, indexof

I need to write a function that will return me the index of element in the array data

adding my code that I wrote already :

```
public synchronized int indexOf(String element) {

    for (String data : data) {

        if (data.equals (element)) {

            indexOf (element);
        }
    }

    return indexOf (element);
}
```

I get a highlight on indexOf:
Method `indexOf()` recurses infinitely and can only end by throwing an exception... which exception will you recommend? thank you in advance.

Comment: you return the same function as you call, you call indexOf with some element and then you want to return it on the same element, this causes infinite recursion, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: thanks , im trying to return the indexOf a value "element" in the array named data.

Comment: where you get data from, you should add more code, I have tried to improve your question consider accepting the edit and add more code then

Comment: You method does not contain a single attempt to actually return a number. All it does, is invoking itself again. IntelliJ analyzed the code to conclude that it will never return, which is a symptom of the lack of an actual return of an index in your code. But instead of asking how you could make the warning go away, you should focus on adding the actual implementation returning an index. Once you solved the actual task, the warning will disappear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your code makes no attempt at returning a position (int). It only recursively calls itself, regardless of whether it finds element or not.

What you probably would want to do with this approach is to return the correct position inside the if where you identify the element, however, your code does not track your current position.

I'm not sure this problem is suitable for recursion, but it's possible to do. First though, there are two other non-recursive solutions.

Simply call List.indexOf():

```
public synchronized int indexOf(String element) {
    return data.indexOf(element);
}
```

Iterate:

```
public synchronized int indexOf(String element) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        if (data.get(i).equals (element)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So far I assumed data to be a List. If instead data is an array, String[], you can still iterate:

```
public synchronized int indexOf(String element) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        if (data[i].equals (element)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Edit**

Recursive solution:

```
public synchronized int indexOf(String element) {
    return internalIndexOfRecursive(element, 0);
}

private synchronized int internalIndexOfRecursive(String element, int pos) {
    if(pos >= dataArray.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (data[pos].equals(element)) {
        return pos;
    }
    return internalIndexOfRecursive(element, pos + 1);
}
```